# I changed places with my brother. (places which is a plural form is adequate? and what does this sentence mean?)

Tags: phrase-meaning

> I changed places with my brother.

'places' which is a plural form is adequate? And what does this sentence mean? Does it just mean that he changed seats with his brother?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your place, your brother's place: two places (therefore plural). They exchanged positions (places). If they were seated, they sat on each other's former seats.